# UIActivityController Not Showing full on screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

i am Presenting UIActivityController But it Showing Half on screen.[image]

```
 let textToShare = "This is awesome!  Check out this website about it!"
    if let myWebsite = NSURL(string:urlShare) {
        let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        //New Excluded Activities Code
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]

        self.navigationController!.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Are you testing in simulator?

Comment: @YogeshMv it behave same on both physical device and simulator

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to `self.presentViewController` on the current `ViewController` instead of on the `self.navigationController`.

I use to have this issue as my `rootViewController` is larger and therefore when presenting using the `self.navigationController` it get cut off.

Comment: yes i tried both, self.present and as above with navigation, but no effect.

Comment: Can you try debug or print the current ViewController view size? Just to be sure that it is correct

Answer (score 0):

Try adding inside a POP UPViewController

```
var popup = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: controller)
popup.presentPopoverFromRect(CGRectMake(self.view!.frame.size.width / 2, self.view!.frame.size.height / 4, 0, 0), inView: self.view!, permittedArrowDirections: .Any, animated: true)
```

here, controller is your **activityVC**